# Error when login in putty "refusing non sftp session"

Tags: debian, ssh, putty

When I log with Putty, Putty close after entering the password. When reading the /var/log/auth.log, it says "refusing non-sftp session".
I added a line in /etc/sudoers to have access in WinSCP the other day, but I commented it and reboot but still have the error. So I'm not sure if it is related.

How can I fix this?

Thank you

Comment: Does the server's /etc/ssh/sshd_config file include a `ForceCommand` directive?

Comment: The account you're logging into:  is it configured for SSH access or restricted to only SFTP access?

Comment: @steeldriver Ah yes, I see one. I just commented it and restart the ssh service and it worked. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

@steeldriver commented the solution. There was a `ForceCommand` directive in the /etc/ssh/sshd_config file. After removing it, I restarted the server using `sudo service ssh restart` and it worked.